# Why file is being overwritten in the android external storage?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write student id's in a text file in the sdcard. I have already created a file named `students.txt` in my sdcard.

The problem is that when I write a value, and read the file, I only get the last value in the file. When I open my file I can only see the last value written in it.

What am I doing wrong? I'm writing the file in append mode using `outputStreamWriter` but still the problem remains the same.

```
    //function to insert
private void myInsertFunc(String data) {
    try {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/" + FILENAME);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
        outputStreamWriter.append(data);

        outputStreamWriter.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student ID: " + data + " Inserted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//function to read
private void myReadFunc() {
    try {
            //InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        //InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.student);
        File file = new File("/sdcard/" + FILENAME);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //if(receiveString.contains(data))
                //{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student ID: " + receiveString , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //break;
                //}
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStreamReader.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [`new FileInputStream(file,true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) to open file in append mode.

Comment: @S.D. Thanks its working but now I don't have to write outputStreamWriter.append() anymore? Instead I write outputStreamWriter.write()?

Comment: @user2738231 Plain `OutputStream` accepts bytes. You need `outputStreamWriter` to easily write characters. Even better option is `FileWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with FileOutputStream and others. They were always creating a new file, when writing. **FileWriter** solved it for me. Should look something like this:

```
private void myInsertFunc(String data) {
    //opens andor creates the file students.txt in the folder /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<your package name>/files/
    File file = new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), "students.txt");
    try {
        //create a filewriter and set append modus to true
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        fw.append(data);
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
```

}

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
    File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ,FILENAME);

    try {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFile, true);

        try{
          fw.write("Hello, world!");
        }finally {
          fw.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```